# Get previous element of a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, iteration

for several reason I have `Dictionary<string, string>` and I'm checking it in a foreach loop. I have no way (at least I didn't find a smart solution) to replace it either with a list, array or a `Dictionary<int, string>`. The dictionary is composed of server name, status of the package (2 strings).

I'm trying to get the previous element in the foreach cycle, in order to compare it with the current element.

My code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair <string,string> pair in packageDistribution) { 
     if (pair.Value == "package distribution complete") { 
          // print pair.Key + " - Installed"; 
     } else {
         // print pair.Key + " - " + pair.Value
     } 
     if (i%3==0) "OR" (i== packageDistribution.count) { 
       // print the values \n 
     } 
}
```

I need to group them 3 by 3 to save space, but my problem is I would like to print to new line even if the current element differs from the previous one:

```
pair.Key.substring(0,4) != previousElement.substring(0,4)
```

My servers look like `NLDN1234, NLDN1235, NSTM2345, NSTM9874` and I would like to group them depending on their names.

Does anyone have a smart suggestion?

Comment: Declare a variable for the previous element and hold onto it.

Comment: a dictionary is the wrong data structure for an ordered traversal

Comment: Is this actually your code? `if (i%3==0) "OR" (i== packageDistribution.count)` doesn't seem like *valid* c#.

Comment: How can I do it if I can't index the dictionary. Actually even if I save dictionary.keys.toArray() > array[0] to a variable, how can I properly update it in the foreach cycle?

Comment: not "OR" but ||. I had problem finding the bars in my macbook :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be prety much straight forward,

```
 Dictionary<string, string> svrs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            svrs.Add("NLDN1234", "ok");
            svrs.Add("NLDN1235", "ok");
            svrs.Add("NSTM2345", "ok");
            svrs.Add("NSTM9874", "ok");

            SortedDictionary<string, string> sortedSvrs = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(svrs);

            for (int i = 0; i < sortedSvrs.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                var key = sortedSvrs.Keys.ElementAt(i);
                Console.WriteLine(key +" " + sortedSvrs[key]);
                // any extra operation
                //
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your code does what you think - there's no guarantee of ordering on the key value pairs in a dictionary; they can be in any order at all, and might even be in different orders in different runs of your application.

If you need them in a particular order, you should explicitly sort them using `OrderBy()`, and if you need to group them, use `GroupBy()` ...

```
var groupsInOrder 
    = packageDistribution.GroupBy(p => p.Key.SubString(0,4))
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
foreach(var group in groupsInOrder)
{ 
    int index = 0;
    foreach(var pair in group)
    {
        // Handle item
        if (++index%3==0)
        {
            // New line
        }
    }
    // New line
}
```

Comment: Or if you're using .NET 4 use the new `SortedDictionary`

Comment: They are already ordered since they come from an SQL query ran with order by clause. Ordering is not the issue. My issue is to get server with a different hostname (the 1st 4 digits) printed to a new line. And to detect if the server has a different hostname, I need to compare its name against the previous printed/stored server hostname

Comment: @user, the point is that the dictionary does not preserve order. You may have put elements into it in a given order, but that does not mean elements come out of it in the same order. That's not its job. Its job is to provide fast lookups of values based on unique keys.

Comment: I followed you suggestion, but how can I access the Value property after using group by?

Comment: And I don't want to group all of them in 1 entry. I need to print out all of them, but I would like to have a new line as soon as the server name differs from the previous, for more than 4 digits (the initials ones). the for cycle sounds logic, but I don't see how I can do it having a dictionary on which I need to access both keys and Values

Comment: You can easily get at the items in each group - I'll update the answer to show how; essentially the group has a `Key` and is itself enumerable to "get at" the items grouped together.

Answer (score -3):

Can't you use a tradition for loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < packageDistribution.Count; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
        // check for packageDistribution at i against i-1
    }
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: A dictionary cannot* be used in such a way. (*Unless the dictionary was `<int, X>`, and the keys were 0..n-1, at which point you probably only needed an array and the dictionary was quite pointless. In this case, the dictionary is `<string, string>`, so the `for` directly against it is right out.)

Comment: Instead you can use packageDistribution.Keys.Count , find the key from the index and find the value from key